# Is it possible to duplicate/copy a batch of contributions?

Tags: civicontribute, recurring-contributions

We have a group of donors that make monthly contributions of equal value. Is it possible to duplicate or copy a previous month's batch and change the date as appropriate and post the new copied batch? This would save a lot of work in re-entering the contributions.

Comment: Perhaps export the contributions' pertinent info into a csv, change the dates and import back as different contributions. I don't know of a way within the UI itself